# Which positive integers satisfies $a^{b^2} = b^a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

How one can find all integers satisfying $a\geq 1,b\geq 1,a^{b^2} = b^a$? I think that the solutions are $ (a,b)=(1, 1), (16, 2),(27, 3)$.

Comment: This is from IMO 1997.

Comment: HINT Take logs.

Comment: @wythagoras and therefore presumably has a proof at http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/

Comment: See here: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1238p3845